# Reverse Indexing w/ Step

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, reverse

I want to get every second digit from a string from right to left.

My code is:

```
def getDigit(creditCard):
    for i in creditCard[::-2]:
        print(i)
    print(creditCard[::-2])

getDigit("0123456789")
```

But this returns the numbers: 9, 7, 5, 3, 1

And I would like it to return: 8, 6, 4, 2, 0

Answer (score 1):

Wow sorry figured it out:

```
def getDigit(creditCard):
    newString = creditCard[::-1]
    for i in creditCard[::2]:
        print(i)

getDigit("0123456789")
```